# Cant find out reason Axis2+Rampart server internal error 500

Tags: apache-axis, rampart

Please help.
I met a problem when I built a server side rampart service. Im using Axis2 server to receive a Rampart client request.
I got a bad response in my Eclipse axis client. The server side is also in local.
Please see the full stack trace(log4j) below. I can only see an ClassNotFound exception for JuiCEProviderOpenSSL, but someone else said I can ignore it. 
And I suspect the bold part causes this issue because after that a builder started to create fault message.
So, it makes me crazy. I can find out nothing about this issue.
Please help me. Thanks. Also, forgive my format, it's the first time to ask here.T-T

axis2.log - log4j

```
2012-05-22 18:00:52,585 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter  - Calling MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush
2012-05-22 18:00:52,585 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.rampart.MESSAGE  - *********************** RampartReceiver received 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="CertId-984C299ACFD3E6AABA13376808432101">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-1">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
<ds:Reference URI="#Id-6349096">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
<ds:DigestValue>7Fk2H6qKHzE7LpXN0BbMnULTuZk=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
c4XDzwPEh58ungiFCp7QaF+LvTjRqW3gE5iiLwWWJiq+AUVyN6l4zN2zRmpWhnAoNr9ecP48ZjkS
pk7LY8DsjEXLQ6j4mroM+fm9vuEoeXlVUmSLezC0cByVBGYDHNxLFC5hpVGYAhfC4gOqZBhmtT3U
ZNGn/5ZjR1aQowUrveCaBQ8Zoz8YjUnMsmdgDK9VD3G2gPwJ3Hujb4TicVP8jN9/FNn7jPPKFRDr
cqjvyApVEj1xn/VcpYlnpJxWG2/Jv9pLNTCBBnHE4gGXRjae5ZznLLYESeEaYRNYWqSKz51F28fU
+Imkj7qS06e8WHcxh2SnKat1fVwM6Agj4D5PnQ==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-984C299ACFD3E6AABA13376808432422">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STRId-984C299ACFD3E6AABA13376808432423"><wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-984C299ACFD3E6AABA13376808432101" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" /></wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-6349096"><ns1:concat xmlns:ns1="http://ttdev.com/ss"><s1>xyz</s1><s2>123</s2></ns1:concat></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

2012-05-22 18:00:53,570 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig  - The provider BC was added at position: 2
2012-05-22 18:00:53,570 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader  - org.apache.security.juice.provider.JuiCEProviderOpenSSL
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.security.juice.provider.JuiCEProviderOpenSSL
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:185)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.loadProvider(WSSConfig.java:605)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.addJceProvider(WSSConfig.java:662)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.staticInit(WSSConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.<init>(WSSConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getNewInstance(WSSConfig.java:333)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getDefaultWSConfig(WSSConfig.java:342)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.<init>(RampartMessageData.java:345)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:78)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPWorker.service(HTTPWorker.java:296)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.doService(AxisHttpService.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.handleRequest(AxisHttpService.java:187)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.HttpServiceProcessor.run(HttpServiceProcessor.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2012-05-22 18:00:53,585 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig  - The provider JuiCE could not be added: org.apache.security.juice.provider.JuiCEProviderOpenSSL
2012-05-22 18:00:53,585 [HttpConnection-8080-1] TRACE org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder  - START_ELEMENT: 
2012-05-22 18:00:53,585 [HttpConnection-8080-1] TRACE org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder  -   QName: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security

2012-05-22 18:00:53,632 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil  - Loading Signature crypto
2012-05-22 18:00:53,632 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine  - Processing security header in normal path
2012-05-22 18:00:53,632 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil  - Loading encryption crypto
2012-05-22 18:00:53,632 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil  - Trying the signature crypto info
2012-05-22 18:00:53,632 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil  - Loading Signature crypto
**2012-05-22 18:00:53,632 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine  - enter processSecurityHeader()
2012-05-22 18:00:53,648 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine  - Processing WS-Security header for '' actor.
2012-05-22 18:00:53,679 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.client.Options  - getAction (null) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@12cfd62
2012-05-22 18:00:53,679 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext  - Old WSAAction is (null)
2012-05-22 18:00:53,679 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext  - New WSAAction is (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault)
2012-05-22 18:00:53,679 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.client.Options  - setAction Old action is (null)
2012-05-22 18:00:53,679 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.client.Options  - setAction New action is (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault)
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] TRACE org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference  - hasAnonymousAddress: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous is Anonymous: true
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] TRACE org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference  - hasAnonymousAddress: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous is Anonymous: true
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.util.MessageContextBuilder  - start createFaultEnvelope()**
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.util.MessageContextBuilder  - faultCode == null
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.util.MessageContextBuilder  - context.isSOAP11() = true
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.util.MessageContextBuilder  - End createFaultEnvelope()
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper  - [MessageContext: logID=19f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] isFaultRedirected: FaultTo is null. Returning isReplyRedirected
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper  - [MessageContext: logID=19f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] isReplyRedirected: ReplyTo is null. Returning false
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] TRACE org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] sendFault:null
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Checking pre-condition for Phase "MessageOut"
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking phase "MessageOut"
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking Handler 'AddressingOutHandler' in Phase 'MessageOut'
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] TRACE org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingOutHandler  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Addressing is disabled. Not adding WS-Addressing headers.
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Checking post-conditions for phase "MessageOut"
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Checking pre-condition for Phase "Security"
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking phase "Security"
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking Handler 'SecurityOutHandler' in Phase 'Security'
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking Handler 'Apache Rampart outflow handler' in Phase 'Security'
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Checking post-conditions for phase "Security"
2012-05-22 18:00:53,695 [HttpConnection-8080-1] TRACE org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference  - hasAnonymousAddress: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous is Anonymous: true
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.client.Options  - getAction (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@12cfd62
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext  - SoapAction is (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault)
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender  - SOAP Action from messageContext : (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault)
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.OMOutputFormat  - Start getContentType: OMOutputFormat [ mimeBoundary =null rootContentId=null doOptimize=false doingSWA=false isSOAP11=true charSetEncoding=UTF-8 xmlVersion=null contentType=null ignoreXmlDeclaration=false autoCloseWriter=true actionProperty=null optimizedThreshold=0]
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.OMOutputFormat  - getContentType= {text/xml}   OMOutputFormat [ mimeBoundary =null rootContentId=null doOptimize=false doingSWA=false isSOAP11=true charSetEncoding=UTF-8 xmlVersion=null contentType=text/xml ignoreXmlDeclaration=false autoCloseWriter=true actionProperty=null optimizedThreshold=0]
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  - contentType from the OMOutputFormat =text/xml
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  - contentType returned =text/xml; charset=UTF-8
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  - start writeTo()
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  -   preserve=false
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  -   isOptimized=false
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  -   isDoingSWA=false
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter  - Creating MTOMXMLStreamWriter
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter  - OutputStream =class org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpResponseImpl$AutoCommitOutputStream
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter  - OMFormat = OMOutputFormat [ mimeBoundary =null rootContentId=null doOptimize=false doingSWA=false isSOAP11=true charSetEncoding=UTF-8 xmlVersion=null contentType=text/xml ignoreXmlDeclaration=false autoCloseWriter=true actionProperty=null optimizedThreshold=0]
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] TRACE org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter  - Call Stack =DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axiom.om.util.CommonUtils.callStackToString(CommonUtils.java:78)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.<init>(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:100)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:191)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:364)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:241)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.sendFault(AxisEngine.java:526)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.doService(AxisHttpService.java:320)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.handleRequest(AxisHttpService.java:187)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.HttpServiceProcessor.run(HttpServiceProcessor.java:82)
    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils  - XMLStreamWriter is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamWriterWrapper
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl  - Could not close builder or parser due to:
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl  - builder is null
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter  - Calling MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.wire  - << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal server error
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.wire  - << Date: Tue, 22 May 2012 10:00:53 GMT
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.wire  - << Server: Simple-Server/1.1
2012-05-22 18:00:53,710 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.wire  - << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.wire  - << Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter  - close
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  - end writeTo()
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils  - Did not find RequestResponseTransport cannot set response written
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "Security"
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'Apache Rampart outflow handler' in Phase 'Security'
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'SecurityOutHandler' in Phase 'Security'
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "MessageOut"
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=09f9baf1b4a9bb41bd81e508daa5dfcc964b902ec7eb7e33] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'AddressingOutHandler' in Phase 'MessageOut'
2012-05-22 18:00:53,726 [HttpConnection-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService  - Remote address of the connection : 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the issue, however, I dont think my solution can help others because I made a very silly mistake.

I think the way I solve the problem is more valuable.  I debugged the source code and traced every step to find out the position of the exception.

Next, I found that Rampart could not get security configuration from services.xml in which I put the Rampart configuration.

The error occurred because I missed the `xmlns='..../rampart/policy'` announcement.  Therefor, the code couldn't recognize them as a `RampartConfig` object.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much great if you have attached the service policy as well. What is the algorithm suit used in your policy. The JCE is need to be installed in your JVM in many cryptographic operations specially in cases where keys that are longer than 128bit is required. Refer to **my** blog at http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/03/java-cryptography-extension-jce.html , install JCE and try the service again.